# React Native Error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"GameScreen"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I know that this issue has been brought up before but I have not found any answer that works for me.

I simply want to navigate from screen "Start" to screen "Game", using App.js as the router.

App.js:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {  
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start">
          <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={StartingScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Game" component={GameScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

StartingScreen.js:

```
const StartingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

//lots of code

return (
//more code
<Button title="Begin" onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('GameScreen')}}/>
)
```

This gives me the error in the title with ("Do you have a game named 'GameScreen'?") and nothing happens. I have tried following the React Navigation docs, but in their example they put everything in App.js, that does not work for me. Other things I have tried include exporting the navigation stack to StartingScreen.js, changing the arguments of navigation.navigate(), placing the navigator inside StartingScreen.js.

GameScreen is spelled exactly the same in all places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your screen name is given 'Game' in the stack navigator, you should navigate to 'Game' instead of 'GameScreen'.

```
onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Game')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below

```
const StartingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

//lots of code

return (
//more code
<Button title="Begin" onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Game')}}/>
)
```

You are giving the component name but you should provide the name of the screen that you give in the stack which is 'Game'